# code igniter updating a row with multiple values to a column

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting a array to my model. Say array has an value 1 and 2.

Now I need to update this to a single column 1,2 so that column will look like this

Column

1,2

```
foreach($x as $y){
 $this->db->where('column',4);
 $this->db->set('id',$data);
 $this->db->update('table');
 }
```

But this is only update 2, it is omitting 1. Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode)? `$this->db->set('id', implode(',', $data));`

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean: `$this->db->where('id', 4); $this->db->set('column', $data);`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `implode`

For example:

```
  $data = [1,2]
  $comma_data = implode(",", $data)
```

Then update column with `$comma_data`

Comment: :When i print_r $comma_data, I am getting two values but in database only one value is getting saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save multiple values in a column put them in 
an array and serialize them. Than save it in column.
Make the column type text.

```
$array['name']      =   'test';
$array['otherinfo'] =   'otherinfo';

$data   =   serialize($array);

foreach($x as $y)
{
    $this->db->where('column',4);
    $this->db->set('id',$data);
    $this->db->update('table');
}
```

When you select you can unserialize the array using unserialize();

Answer (score 0):

I was having wrong data type, I figured it out.